# AWS API gateway authorizer cognito userid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

https://*myapi*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users/**userid**

I want my cognito users to only have acces to their own **/users/userid**

Is this possible using the built in cognito API authorizer or do I need a custom lambda authorizer that extracts the userid from the token and compares it to the path?

​

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is currently possible with standard Cognito user pool authorizers, but should be possible with Lambda authorizers. The input to your Lambda authorizer will contain the full method ARN, which includes the resource path: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html

I recommend evaluating if you can store any of this user data within Cognito directly, via custom attributes, if that works for your application: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

Comment: I need to store zero or more ID's of another object that that user has access to. I don't think that would be very convenient to use custom cognito attributes for that. But thanks for your reply